# VMware workstation install problem

Tags: windows-7, installation, vmware-workstation

I've been trying to install VMware workstation 7.1.4 on my windows 7 computer.
I know I've already posted something similar to this, but this totally different situation.
Whenever I open the installer, this grey window labeled VMware workstation setup opens and nothing happens. Works on vista, but I don't use my Vista for this kinda stuff anymore. Help

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to include a screenshot or something?

Comment: Cant help if you provided not enough information, screenshot at least, VMware workstation version, etc..?

Comment: @beth22- vmware workstation version- the latest one, and sorry, thats all the information i have. i tried to put a screenshot up, but it did not work, the site said something about me not being an old enough member (im new to superuser.

Comment: @Nick- yes, i tried, but i wasnt alwed. superuser said i wasnt an old enough member.

Comment: "similar to ... totally different situation"

Comment: Were there any errors during vmware installation? Are there any errors in your windows event logs, particularly with a time stamp near your last attempted launch of vmware?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a quite common problem with many solutions.

From [When installing VMware Workstation, the Setup window displays a blank screen](http://d3planet.com/rtfb/?KrugUtgl).
To resolve this issue, you must replace certain files with the original version. To replace the files:

> Open a command prompt and run these
>   commands to re-register the necessary
>   files :
>
> 32-bit version of Windows:
>
> ```
> regsvr32 jscript.dll
> regsvr32 vbscript.dll
> ```
>
> 64-bit version of Windows:
>
> ```
> cd C:\windows\syswow64
> regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\jscript.dll
> regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\vbscript.dll
> ```
>
> Restart Windows.

Other [solutions](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1640161) may be to :

- run the installation from an empty folder (only the installation package should be there)
- make sure your AV does not block (better disable all antivirus and firewall)
- make sure there are no processes running like webcam.exe or fixcamera.exe
- run the installation package from the command line by adding `/z action=install`
- run the installation using "Run as administrator"
- go to registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\` and delete a key `L` (make a backup first)

Or you can try this one:

- To uninstall any old version, go to C:\Windows\Installer
- Add the "Authors" column and sort by it
- One of the .msi files with have a "VMware" author
- Double-click it and follow through with the uninstall steps
- To install the new version, run cmd.exe as administrator and do:

> cd install-file-directory
>   install-file.exe /e tempfolder
>  cd
>   tempfolder
>  run the .msi file
>   (vmware workstation.msi)

Comment: last one helped. but before i uninstall the vmware and then did this instruction.

Comment: i was having this same problem but i was running it from another partition and moving it to the system drive fixed it

Comment: I have done whatever has been written above and it has not worked. Please help

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kU2-SnA5zc) helped me:

1. Go to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones
   ```
2. Remove the key which has a box as name `"[]"`.

Comment: This alone fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The MSI  `C:Windows\TEMP\vmware_1402472938\vmwareplayer_x86.msi` failed: 'Could not write value to key
\SYSTEM\currentControlSet\Services\Vmware\Performance'. Verify that you have sufficient access to that key

If you have this problem  then this is not problem of VMware. Whenever you have MSI problem then its the problem of  Windows Installer.

In these type of problem first go and check if the required folder is present in the Hkey_local.  Eg(`\SYSTEM\currentControlSet\Services\Vmware\Performance`). IF not  then create the required folder.
After long hours on computer I realized that the problem is so simple.

- On command prompt  Type regedit
- The click HKEY_Local_Machine.
- Then try to find all the folder , if the folder is missing  create the required folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but now I was able to install VMWare workstation 8 successfully on my Windows 7 32 bit laptop with the above said steps.

1. I re-registered the necessary files rvgsvr files in command prompt.
2. I deleted the registry entry L from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\`
3. I copied the installation file to the system drive(C:).
4. Then I was able to install the vmware.

Answer (score 1):

The same installer is used and the same problem did occur with VMWare Workstation 9.

*setup.exe* reveals itself (right click:Properties>Details) to contain a boostrap.exe file which wraps around an msiexec file. The blank frame is actually an HTML site. Right click and "Show Source" to confirm. The underlying problem is a JavaScript error.

The problem is common on Windows systems which have removed the Internet Explorer.

**Solution:**

Open a terminal and run `setup.exe /e FolderpathToExtractTo`

e.g. `setup.exe /e c:\VMWareSetup`

Go in the directory and run **vmwareworkstation_x64.msi** or **vmwareworkstation_x86.msi** and wait till it finishes. That's it. It definitely worked for **VMWare Workstation 9.0**

Be aware that an extraction with 7zip will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it by renaming the file from `setup.exe` to `buggy.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

In a file named, for example, `uninstall.cmd`:

```
echo off
MsiExec.exe /qn /X{0D94F75A-0EA6-4951-B3AF-B145FA9E05C6} /norestart
rd /s/q "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation"
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{0D94F75A-0EA6-4951-B3AF-B145FA9E05C6} /f
exit
```

Of course, adjust the MSI-Code (0D94F75A-0EA6-4951-B3AF-B145FA9E05C6) 
-> Workstation 9.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If you have avast installed

> To solve this problem just uncheck "hardware virtualization" checkbox on AvastUI troubleshooting page. (reboot is required to propagate this setting change)

more info [here](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=126795.0)

Comment: Please post the relevant information from the link in your answer to avoid link rot, for more information please see [answer]